# Substrate: How to perform Parachain Runtime Upgrade via Democracy using Chopsticks

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I am trying to perform a runtime upgrade using [Acala's Chopsticks](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/tree/master).
I followed the [authorize > enact an upgrade flow](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/upgrade-a-parachain/) for my parachain, and it works.

To produce blocks in local Polkadot, i connected through ws and executed the command:

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "method": "dev_newBlock", "params": [ {"count": 1000} ]}
```

However when I checked `paras` > `futureCodeUpgrades`, I do not see my parachain.
Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in [StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/how-to-perform-parachain-runtime-upgrade-via-democracy-using-chopsticks/9164#9164), and I finally figured it out with the help of my teammates.

Basically, just produce blocks in both the relaychain and the parachain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully executed the runtime upgrade and it has been enacted on your parachain, but you cannot see your parachain listed under **paras > futureCodeUpgrades**, it's possible that there might be a few reasons for this.

**Upgrade Status**: The runtime upgrade might not have been fully processed or confirmed by the network yet. It's essential to wait for the network to finalize the upgrade before it appears in the futureCodeUpgrades section.

**Node Synchronization**: If your local Polkadot node is not fully synchronized with the network, it might not show the most recent upgrades and changes. Ensure your node is fully synchronized to get the latest data.

**Wrong Endpoint**: Verify that you are connecting to the correct endpoint of your local node that is responsible for querying the futureCodeUpgrades information.

**Parachain Configuration**: Make sure you have correctly configured your parachain to participate in future code upgrades. If your parachain is not configured for this, it won't appear in the futureCodeUpgrades list.

**Parachain Identifier**: Double-check that you are looking for the correct parachain identifier when checking for the upgrade status. The identifier uniquely identifies your parachain on the network.

If you have waited for some time and still don't see your parachain listed under futureCodeUpgrades, it might be beneficial to check the logs of your local node or reach out to the Acala community or support channels for further assistance. They can help you troubleshoot the issue and ensure your runtime upgrade was successful and properly recorded on the network.

Comment: thanks for this insight, it's very useful once I do an actual runtime upgrade in the real chains. :D

Comment: did you get any part of this answer from an AI?